# What is value of following integral ( Solve by complex analysis)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying exercises of textbook Ponnusamy and Silvermann and I am struck on this problemof Section 9.37.

> Evaluate the following integral along different simple closed curves not passing through 0, +1, -1.

$\int_{C} \frac{e^{z-1} -1 } {z^2 (z^2 -1) }  dz $.

I am weak in these type of problems ( ie Evaluating of integrals). I shall be really thankful if you can tell how to attempt it. I have read examples from textbook and could understand them.

Kindly tell me 2 curves around which I should calculate the integral and why you are choosing that curve. I will first try to calculate it myself.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know if the concept of residues and their relation to integrals over closed curves?

Comment: @Arthur yes I have read theorems and examples and I could understand them.

Comment: @Arthur but the problem is due to the reason that I was taught by terrible instructor and had to self study and couldn't try problems and fells lack of confident in it.Now I am trying exercises but couldn't solve them.

Comment: Yes, it's always our fault :) $$\oint _{C}f(z)=2\pi i\cdot \sum \operatorname {Res} (f,a_{k})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z):=\frac{e^{z-1} -1 } {z^2 (z^2 -1) }$

Here are 3 possible circular closed loops.

let $R_k$ be the residue at pole $P_k$.

Do you agree that for example, if $C$ is the red circle:

$$\int_C f(z)dz=2i \pi(R_2+R_3)$$

(by residue theorem) ?

Do you know how to compute residues ? (beware, $0$ is a double pole).

In order you are able to check them, here is what I have found:

$$R_1=\tfrac12(e^{-2}-1), \ \ R_2=0, \ \ R_3=-e^{-1}.$$

A full answer would consider each of the $2^3$ subsets of $\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}$ and conclude that there are eventually 4 possible different results:

$$\int_C f(z)dz \ \ = \ \ 0, \ \ 2i \pi R_1, \ \  2i \pi R_3, \ \ 2i \pi(R_1+R_3)$$

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell what are center and radius of the Circles?

Comment: Centers $-1,0,1$, radii $1.5,1,1.5$...